# Unable to create a modal dialog box in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

In the following working demo, on clicking the `see example` link, a modal box appears. The code is in `Bootstrap` (no Angular).

https://codepen.io/manuchadha/pen/PBKYBJ

I want to write the same logic in Angular. I thought of creating a new component and pass the message I want to show in the modal as `Input` like follows:

dialog-box.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-box',
  templateUrl: './dialog-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-box.component.css']
})
export class DialogBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dialogMessage:string; //pass the message to be shown in this modal
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In the `html` of the component, I wrote the `Bootstrap`'s modal code

```
<!--Modal. Should be hidden unless some clicked event makes this visible-->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Example</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{dialogMessage}}</p> <¬-the message passed to this component should show here -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in my other HTML file (in which I have the `see example` link), I want to call this component. But I am unable to figure out how to call the component.

**Problem 1** - I tried to use the modal in the following way but I am getting error  `<small id="language-select-help" class="form-text text-muted"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="some message"></app-dialog-box></small>`

Error is `Parse Error - unexpected token message`. I suppose it is pointing to `[dialogMessage]="some message"`

**Problem 2** - Would the above approach if I have multiple `<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="some message"></app-dialog-box></small>` inn the same html file? The form I am creating has multiple fields and for each field I want to provide `see example` link. My concern is whether I'll end up having multiple `<app-dialog-box` with same id `exampleModal` in the same html page.

UPDATE - I found the answer to problem1. I should use single quotes within double quotes i.e. `<app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="'some message'"</app-dialog-box>`.

But the new problem is that if I use the same logic for all `see example` links then I don't see the correct message  i.e.

`<small id="language-select-help" class="form-text text-muted"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="'some message'"></app-dialog-box></small>`

and

`<small id="question-title-help" class="form-text text-muted"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="'some message2'"></app-dialog-box></small>`

On clicking either of the links, I always get the message `some message` instead of `some message` and `some message2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue (as I earlier suspected) was multiple  had same id `id="exampleModal"`. I resolved it by passing id as well as input when creating

change in dialog-box.component.ts

```
@Input() dialogID:string;
```

change in component's html

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="{{dialogID}}">
```

then call the code as

```
<small id="language-select-help" class="form-text text-muted"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="'some message'" [dialogID]="'id1'"></app-dialog-box></small>
```

and

```
<small id="question-title-help" class="form-text text-muted"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">See Example</a><app-dialog-box [dialogMessage]="'some message2'"  [dialogID]="'id1'"></app-dialog-box></small>
```